# Determining the variables with the highest and lowest values

Tags: php

For example if I have:

```
$person1 = "10";
$person2 = "-";
$person3 = "5";
```

I need to determine the person with the highest number and prepend their string with a "W" and also determine the person with the lowest (numeric) number and prepend their string with a "L"

I am trying to output:

```
$person1 = "W10";
$person2 = "-";
$person3 = "L5";
```

Comment: `$person1 = 'W' . $person1; $person3 = 'L' . $person3`?

Comment: ^That wouldnt work if $person3 has a higher number than $person1. I need to *determine* the person with the highest/lowest number with PHP.

Comment: could you format that data in to an array? then it would be super simple

Comment: Yes I can....what would the solution be if I have it in an array?

Comment: What if there is no highest score? Should they both get `WL` prefixed? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$persons = array(10, '-', '12', 34 ) ; //array of persons, you define this
$max_index = array_search($max = max($persons), $persons);
$min_index = array_search($min = min($persons), $persons);
$persons[$max_index] = 'W' . $persons[$max_index];
$persons[$min_index] = 'L' . $persons[$min_index];

print_r($persons);
```

Hope that helps.  It should give you hints on what functions to use. Peace Danuel

## solution 2

```
foreach((array)$persons as $index=>$value){
        if(!is_numeric($value))continue;
        if(!isset($max_value)){
                $max_value = $value;
                $max_index = $index;
        }
        if(!isset($min_value)){
                $min_value = $value;
                $min_index = $index;
        }
        if( $max_value < $value ){
                $max_value = $value;
                $max_index = $index;
        }
        if( $min_value > $value ){
                $min_value = $value;
                $min_index = $index;
        }
}

@$persons[$max_index] = 'W'.$persons[$max_index];//@suppress some errors just in case
@$persons[$min_index] = 'L'.$persons[$min_index];

print_r($persons);
```

Comment: Hey you got to it before I could append it, but see my other answer to better fulfilled that response you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I would put each of the variables into an array and then use the array sort function.

```
$people = array (
   'person1' => $person1,
   'person2' => $person2,
   'person3' => $person3
);

asort($people);

$f = key($people);

end($people);
$l = key($people);

$people[$f] = 'L' . $people[$f];
$people[$l] = 'W' . $people[$l];
```

Person 1's score could then be reference by using `$people_sorted['person1']`

Comment: I tired this but got an error "Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array"

Comment: This is wrong. arsort returns a boolean value, so its return cannot be used to index an array. Not to mention that the `$people` array is associative and not numerically indexed, therefore you cannot do `[0]` or `[2]`.

Comment: Sorry, realised I made a mistake - I have updated with corrected version.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution that will work with **any** combination of people:

```
$people = array (
   'person1' => 4,
   'person2' => 10,
   'person3' => 0
);

arsort( $people); // Sort the array in reverse order

$first = key( $people); // Get the first key in the array

end( $people);
$last = key( $people); // Get the last key in the array

$people[ $first ] = 'W' . $people[ $first ];
$people[ $last  ] = 'L' . $people[ $last ];

var_dump( $people);
```

**Output:**

```
array(3) {
 ["person2"]=>
  string(3) "W10"
  ["person1"]=>
  int(4)
  ["person3"]=>
  string(2) "L0"
}
```